# How to get empty result set with a CASE statement?

Tags: mysql, vertica

I cannot get an empty result in `CASE` statement. The following query returns `NULL` as the result:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN ('test' IS NULL) THEN (SELECT 'null_result') ELSE (SELECT 'empty_result' WHERE 1<>1) END;
```

I want to get empty result (without any rows).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: That is not my answer, I want to get empty result (without any rows)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a more detailed description of what you want to do. If possible provide a [mcve] as described on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query.  Maybe the usage of `CASE` is wrong in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out `NULL` values in the outer `WHERE` clause.

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN ('test' IS NULL) THEN (SELECT 'null_result') ELSE (SELECT 'empty_result' WHERE 1<>1) END
WHERE CASE WHEN ('test' IS NULL) THEN (SELECT 'null_result') ELSE (SELECT 'empty_result' WHERE 1<>1) END IS NOT NULL;
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT CASE WHEN ('test' IS NULL) THEN (SELECT 'null_result') ELSE (SELECT 'empty_result' WHERE 1<>1) END as result_case
) x
WHERE result_case IS NOT NULL;
```